# When is the leaf of a foliation the level set of a function?

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

Suppose I have a smooth (say $C^1$) codimension one foliation of $P^n$ (open subset of $R^n$ consisting of vectors with all positive components) arising from a smooth $(n-1)$-plane field satisfying the Frobenius conditions. Now take a single leaf $L$; I would like to show that $L$ is the graph of a function defined on some open subset of $P^{n-1}$. If I knew that $L$ was the level set of some function $F$ on $P^n$, say $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 0, \forall x \in P^n$, *and* I knew that $F_n(p) > 0 \; \forall p \in L$, then I could use the "basic" implicit function theorem to conclude that there exists a function $u$ such that $F(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},u(x_1,\ldots,u_{n-1})) = 0$ locally, then proceed to extend it since I know $F_n(p) > 0$ everywhere on $L$.

My question is: Do I know that $L$ is the level set of some function $F$? For reasons outside the scope of this question I *do* know that the normal vector to the tangent plane to $L$, at every point of $L$, has $n$th component $> 0$ (I can compute this manually since I know the vector fields giving rise to the distribution), but to me that doesn't seem to make things directly amenable to an application of the implicit function theorem. I have a feeling that there is some way to look at this which makes the answer to my question very obvious (and the question itself silly), but I *have* tried to work this out and being very obsessive about my proofs I wanted to ask here.

Any info or advice appreciated.

**Edit to add information.**: I understand that $L$, being an integral manifold, *is* a graph, locally, say on some domain $U$. I believe my condition that the last component of the normal to the tangent plane, at every point $p \in L$, means that $U$ can be extended to a maximal domain $D$ by means of the implicit function theorem. I just am searching for the proper application of that theorem given that I don't know that $L$ can be  given by a function of the form $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 0$.

**Edit to clarify my objective** I want to show that any leaf $L$ of a particular foliation (arising from a specific $n$-plane distribution on $P^n$) is the graph of some function $u : D \rightarrow P$ where $D$ is an open subset of $P^{n-1}$. This specific distribution gives me the condition on the normals mentioned in the previous edit. I believe the way to prove that is to show that any neighborhood $U$ on which we *know* $L$ is a graph (there has to be one since an integral manifold *is* locally a graph) can always be extended to a maximal domain unless $u$ goes to infinity or zero on its boundary, and I believe the way to do that is via the implicit function theorem, utilizing the condition on the normals. I just don't know *how* to prove it this way.

**Edit to give specifics**: Let $n=3$; I have two strictly positive, $C^2$ functions on $P^3$, $m^1(x,y,z)$ and $m^2(x,y,z)$. The vector fields are $X^1 = \partial/\partial x - m^1 \partial/\partial z$ and $X^2 = \partial/\partial y - m^2 \partial/\partial z$ and I impose  the following condition on the derivatives of $m^1,m^2$: $ -\partial m^2/\partial x + \partial m^1/\partial y + m^1 \partial m^2/\partial z - m^2 \partial m^1/\partial z = 0$. This should make the $2$ plane distribution generated by $X,Y$ involutive and so by Frobenious there is a smooth foliation $\mathscr{F}$ of $P^3$ by integral manifolds of the distribution. The normal vector to the plane tangent to a leaf $L$ at a point $p$ can be computed as $\pm(m^1(p),m^2(p),1)$, I take the positive normal. My understanding is that under these conditions (in particular, that the normal has strictly positive last component at *every* point of $P^3$) each leaf $L \in \mathscr{F}$ is the graph of some function $u : D \rightarrow P$, where $D$ is some open set of $P^2$. I am looking for details on proving (if possible) my understanding, and my idea was to use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: The leaf being locally given as a level set is a consequence of Frobenius's Theorem. It seems you are asking whether the leaf can be given *globally* as a level set, correct? If so, I'd expect that to be false in general (even for codimension 1). So are you seeking sufficient (and necessary?) conditions for when this global level set repr. exists?

Comment: The ultimate objective is, yes, to prove that the leaf is globally a graph. IOW, given a neighborhood in which it is a graph, extend it to a maximal domain. I believe this can be done, via the implicit function theorem, if I know that the normal to the tangent plane at each point of the leaf has strictly positive last coordinate, which it does. I just don't know precisely how to apply that theorem in the case where I don't have a function implicitly defining the leaf.

Comment: Both are false already in the case $n=2$. For instance, a leaf need not be a closed subset and level sets are always closed.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: Understood, but in this case, IF the leaf is a graph of a function, say, $u : D \rightarrow P$, where $D$ is some open set in $P^{n-1}$ then I believe I can show it's closed.  The title of my question is unfortunately misleading, I tend to not ask direct questions, rather I ask about things that may lead me to my result. I will edit the original post to make it more clear exactly what it is I want to do. If that doesn't work then I'll repost with a better title. Sorry.

Comment: What you are claiming "you can show" is also false in dimension 2.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: I am sure you are right and I am wrong. Perhaps I have left out a vital piece of the puzzle or I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the situation. I am going to edit the question and detail, for $n=3$ (since I am also most probably wrong in any dimension) the situation and my argument. If you have the time and inclination perhaps you can point out the issue. It would help me immensely to know right now that the path I'm going down will lead me nowhere. Thanks for taking the time to respond.